# Finding indices of elements in vector

Tags: python, numpy

I have a vector `orig` which is a p dimensional vector

Now, I sampled c elements from this vector (with replacement), lets call it `sampled_vec`. So basically,`sampled_vec` has elements from `orig`
Now, I want to find out the indices of these elements (in `sampled_vec`) from `orig`.
Probably, an example would make this clear.

```
   orig = [1,2,3,4,5]
   sampled_vec = [3,1,3]

   indices = [2,0,2]
```

Comment: Is `orig` always sorted?

Comment: @ajcr: No.. That is just an example

Comment: are elements in orig unique?

Comment: @azalea: yes. We can assume that.. or lets retreive the first element..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example using list comprehensions:

```
In [1]: orig = [1,2,3,4,5]

In [2]: sampled_vec = [3,1,3]

In [3]: indices = [orig.index(i) for i in sampled_vec]

In [4]: indices
Out[4]: [2, 0, 2]
```

Comment: will it be easier if orig and sampled_vec are numpy arrays

Comment: Generally `numpy` is quite fast with vectors and matrices but I wouldn't care about performance until the very end. I'd suggest to go on and if you at some point are annoyed by the execution time, fire up a profiler and optimise the bottle necks.

Answer (score 1):

If elements are unique in `orig`.

```
indices = [orig.index(vec) for vec in sampled_vec]
```

Comment: will it be easier if orig and sampled_vec are numpy arrays

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
import numpy as np

out = np.searchsorted(orig, sampled_vec, side='left')
```

Sample run -

```
In [44]: orig = [1,2,3,4,5]
    ...: sampled_vec = [3,1,3,2,5]
    ...: 

In [45]: np.searchsorted(orig, sampled_vec, side='left')
Out[45]: array([2, 0, 2, 1, 4], dtype=int64)
```